# How to check the presence of a specific embbeded code into an html page using php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple problem with no way to manage a simple check online to our customers code presence on their website page. For instance they have to embbed a html code like this one :

```
<div class="Aclass">
    <div data-tag="123456" class="Mandatory Mandatory-test></div>
    <div class="Mandatory Mandatory-dialog">
            <div class="Mandatory Mandatory-test2"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/mustache" name="landing/Execute">
            <a data-tag="Execute-test">Manage</a>
    </script>
</div>
```

I want to be able to know if the code is properly instlled in the website with a timed check like a cron for instance.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you asking how to check markup on your customer's page? Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `stripos()`, it will return false if it doesn't find this string in the user's HTML page. Looks like:

```
$code = "<div class=\"Aclass\">
<div data-tag=\"123456\" class=\"Mandatory Mandatory-test\"></div>
<div class=\"Mandatory Mandatory-dialog\">
        <div class=\"Mandatory Mandatory-test2\"></div>\n    </div>\n    <script type=\"text/mustache\" name=\"landing/Execute\">\n            <a data-tag=\"Execute-test\">Manage</a>\n    </script>\n</div>";
if(!stripos($codeOfPage,$code)){
    // Your code isn't present in the page
}
```